# Mapping a UID on custom module content

Tags: feeds

Dear Drupal Enthusiasts,

I was hoping that one of you may be able to solve a problem I'm having with the Feeds module and its unique identifiers.

Basically, I would like to be able to target a field with a unique identifier like you can do with any ordinarily created content-type. However, I want to do this on a custom module (which has its own form of unique identification).

In other words, I have a field in my custom module that is unique, but Drupal does not know that this field is unique. How do I both tell Drupal that this custom module contains a unique field and identify that field as unique so that I can update content rather than delete it and replace it every time I wish to import data?

Any guidance would be most helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve this problem with a simple fix - though it took a good deal of time to find it, so I figured I'd post it here to inform others in the event they have a similar difficulty.

I simply used the `Field validation` module which gives the user the capability of selecting his/her own UID for any field instance...quite straightforward.

Hope that helps!